# How to change array of object to new array of object with conditions using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, for-loop, object

I have array of object and need to modify and return new array of object

For the below array of object, i need to return new array of object with label, value and children props using javascript.

should change every property value to label, value and if property value is array then embed in children prop as shown in expected output

```
var arrobj = [
  {
    title: "Test A",
    group: ['Travel', 'Health'],
    details: {
      'Travel': ['domestic', 'international'],
      'Health': ['hospital']
   }
  },
  {
    title: "Test B",
    group: ['Finance'],
    details: {
      'Finance': ['family']
   }
  }
]
```

```
Expected Output:

[
 {
   value: "Test A",
   label: "Test A",
   children: [
     {
       value: 'Travel', label: 'Travel',
       children: [
        { value: 'domestic', label: 'domestic'},
        { value: 'international', label: 'international'},
      ]
     },
     {
       value: 'Health', label: 'Health',
       children: [
        { value: 'hospital', label: 'hospital'},
      ]
     }  
   ]
 },
 {
   value: "Test B",
   label: "Test B",
   children: [
      { 
        value: 'Finance', label: 'Finance',
        children: [
          { value: 'family', label: 'family'},
        ]
      }
   ]
 }

]
```

```
Tried

arrrobj.map(e=> {
  label: e.title,  
  value: e.title,
  children: [
     {
       label: e.group;
       value: e.group;
       children: e.details.Travel
     }
   ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```js
arrobj.map(obj => ({
  value: obj.title,
  label: obj.title,
  children: obj.group.map(group => ({
    value: group,
    label: group,
    children: obj.details[group].map(detail => ({
      value: detail,
      label: detail
    }))
  }))
}))
```

```js
var arrobj = [{
    title: "Test A",
    group: ['Travel', 'Health'],
    details: {
      'Travel': ['domestic', 'international'],
      'Health': ['hospital']
    }
  },
  {
    title: "Test B",
    group: ['Finance'],
    details: {
      'Finance': ['family']
    }
  }
];

const output = arrobj.map(obj => ({
  value: obj.title,
  label: obj.title,
  children: obj.group.map(group => ({
    value: group,
    label: group,
    children: obj.details[group].map(detail => ({
      value: detail,
      label: detail
    }))
  }))
}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

like this ?

```
arrobj.map(obj => {
        const children = Object.keys(obj.details).map(value => ({
          value,
          label: value,
          children: obj.details[value].map(child => ({value: child, label: child}))
        }))
        return {
          value: obj.title,
          label: obj.title,
          children
        }
      })
```

or is there any more message ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrobj = [
    {
      title: "Test A",
      group: ['Travel', 'Health'],
      details: {
        'Travel': ['domestic', 'international'],
        'Health': ['hospital']
     }
    },
    {
      title: "Test B",
      group: ['Finance'],
      details: {
        'Finance': ['family']
     }
    }
  ]

  const convertToTree = arrobj.reduce((acc, item)=>{

    const children = Object.entries(item.details).reduce((groupAcc,[group, details])=>{
        groupAcc.push({
            value: group,
            label: group,
            children:details.map(detail => ({
                value:detail,
                label:detail
            }))
        });
        return groupAcc;
    }, []);
    acc.push({
        value:item.title,
        label: item.title,
        children
    })
    return acc
  },[])

console.log(convertToTree);
```